# CloudSearch fuzzy matching of whole string doesn't work

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

I have set up an Amazon CloudSearch domain with records that hold addresses. I want to do a fuzzy text search on an address field.

Say I have a record with the following address:

```
1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA 94043.
```

If I search for `'Amphitheatre Parkway, Muntain View'~5` I get no results. I basically deleted the 'o' in "Mountain" and it doesn't find any results.

If I search for `Muntain~5` it finds it, but again if I search for `Miunntain~5` it doesn't find anything.

I should add I created a free text Analysis Scheme, with no stemming, stopwords or synonyms. This is what is used for the address field which is of type `text`.

How should I set up CloudSearch to be able to do these sort of queries?

Comment: ~ is the fuzzy operator. It means the distance that the text can differ is at most 5. I'm not using any SDK. I am using the CloudSearch console to test it out. Well, they have a fuzzy operator, why would it not support fuzzy searches? I somehow assumed this is what it is supposed to do.

Comment: @BMW CloudSearch is a REST service; doesn't matter what language you're using. And `~` is the CloudSearch fuzzy operator which you can see in their docs http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/searching-text.html . I know you're trying to be helpful but if you're not willing to at least google "cloudsearch fuzzy search" then you're just adding noise to the discussion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Querying `'Amphitheatre Parkway, Muntain View'~5` is actually performing a fuzzy/sloppy *phrase* search, where it's searching for those words within 5 words of one another. I don't think that's what you intended.
2. The `Miunntain~5` query is really interesting: it does indeed return no results, but `miunntain~5` (lowercase m) does:
   [image]

   I did notice that switching between lower and uppercase in my queries does slightly affect the match scores, so perhaps the capital M just makes it too weak a match. I don't have a good explaination for that; it's certainly counterintuitive so maybe it is a bug.
3. Finally your actual question about setting up CloudSearch to handle those queries: unfortunately CloudSearch doesn't expose the "Did you mean..." spellcheck feature from Solr so there isn't really a good way to do this; slapping some tildas on things is about the best you can do.

See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/searching-text.html